# X-CSRF-Token implement guide

Tags: php, ajax, csrf

i am new to X-CSRF-Token technic , can you check it for me if it right ?

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_cookie['x_csrf_tocken'])){
        setcookie('x_csrf_tocken', openssl_encode("random_string"),  time()+86400);
    }
?>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<?php echo $_cookie['x_csrf_tocken']; ?>">

<script>
    //for all ajax calls
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
    });

    //first
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "script.php",
        data: {data: $('#data').val()},
        success: function(data, textStatus){do something ...}
    });

    //another
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "anotherScript.php",
        data: {data: $('#anotherData').val()},
        success: function(data, textStatus){do something else ...}
    });
</script>
```

and on the other side (server side) should be like this :

```
if($_cookie['x_csrf_tocken'] == $_SERVER['HTTP_X-CSRF-TOKEN']){
    finish !
}else{
    busted ..
}
```

and i don't understand why wouldn't the attacker implement a similar script ?

and how can i use this technic for **normal form submit** ?

**another question :** Why not use a stored value in the database instead of cookies ?

and what about this to avoid make for every form a hidden input :

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
        $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='x_csrf_tocken' value='"+$("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")+"' />");
}
```

please be easy much as you can in your answer ...

Comment: Where exactly do you get `COOKIE_CSRF_TOKEN` from? are you really creating a proper CSRF token? Seems odd to create one and define it as a constant. Id like to see the code that creates this value for you.

Comment: In order for this to protect your site, you need to be able to generate as well as verify CSRF tokens, this shows how you're sending the token but doesnt show how you generate or validate them so we cant say if this is a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

For a normal form, have a hidden form field inside the `<form></form>` tags. Like so:

```html
<form method="post" action="/foo">
    <input type="hidden" name="X-CSRF-TOKEN" value="$your_csrf_token">
    // your other input types...
</form>
```

So upon submitting the form, you'll submit the csrf token too.

Comment: thank you so my work is correct ? and what about the other question : Why not use a stored value in the database instead of cookies ?

Comment: For the second part of your question @12 see this article about how CSRF protection works https://medium.com/@barryvdh/csrf-protection-in-laravel-explained-146d89ff1357 its about laravel, but the points are all still relevant